# Prove that $n! = \Omega(n^{100})$

Tags: sorting, computer-science

I justed started studying the sorting algorithm, so i need help solving problems on (big Omega) $\Omega$

How can I Prove that $n! = \Omega(n^{100})$

I know that we write $f(x) = \Omega(g(x))$ if $g(x) = O(f(x))$. This means that there is a constant $c>0$ and a value $x_0$ such that $|f(X)| \ge cg(x)$ whenever $x>x_0$.

Hence from the definition above, I can write
$$n^100 = O(n!)$$

We can find a constant c and a value $x_0$ such that $n^100 \le O(n!)$ for all $x>x_0$.
We could take $c=1$ and $x_0=1$

I don't know if I am correct. Please how should I continue and complete the proof.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `n!` being `Ω(n**100)` is that there is some `c` and some `x₀` such that `n! ≥ c n**100` for all `x ≥ x₀`.  Your choice of `c=x₀=1` says that  3! is bigger than 3^100, which it clearly isn't.

Think about how fast n! grows.  (n + 1)! is n + 1 times bigger than n!

Think about how fact n**100 grows.  (n+1)**100 is ((n + 1)/n) ** 100 bigger than n*100.  For large n, that number is going to get closer and closer to 1.